# Selenium Java : Text retrival from h1 tag

Tags: java, html, selenium, testing

I am aware of `.getAttribute("innerHTML")`, which is one of the ways to retrieve the value of `h1` tag but my HTML looks like this:
[image]

I can reach `h1` tag but not able to reach `innerHTML`.

I want to retrieve text from `innerHTML` using selenium WebDriver in Java

Solution I used :
First I located h1 tag using 
`@FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main\"]/h1")` with element name as Findelement, then used `Findelement.getAttribute("[0].innerHTML")` to retrieve text but while running program is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: Show the code you used please.

Comment: First  I located h1 tag using - @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main\"]/h1") with element name as Findelement, then used Findelement.getAttribute("[0].innerHTML") to retrieve text but while running program is throwing java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: Can you please post such information in your question?

Comment: The h1 element doesn't have the id "main". Therefore Findelement is null.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. I used the below code to retrieve the text.

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
String sText = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main\"]/h1"))).toString();
```