# Why is my Jsoup Code not Returning the Correct Elements?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, web-scraping, jsoup

I am working on an app in Android Studio and am having some trouble web-scraping with JSoup. I have successfully connected to the webpage and returned some basic elements to test the library, but now I cannot actually get the elements I need for my app.

I am trying to get a number of elements with the "data-at" attribute. The weird thing is, a few elements with the "data-at" attribute are returned, but not the ones I am looking for. For whatever reason my code is not extracting ***all*** of the elements that share the "data-at" attribute on the web page.

This is the URL of the webpage I am scraping:
https://express.liatoyotaofcolonie.com/inventory?f=dealer.name%3ALia%20Toyota%20of%20Colonie&f=submodel%3ACamry&f=trim%3ALE&f=year%3A2020

### The method containing the web-scraping code:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String title = "";
        Document doc;
        Log.d(TAG, queryString.toString());
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(queryString.toString()).get();
            Elements content = doc.select("[data-at]");
            for (Element e: content) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.text());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return title;
    }
```

### The results in Logcat

[image]

### The element I want to retrieve

[image]

### One of the elements that is actually being retrieved

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some of the content - including the one you are looking for - is created asyncronously and is not present in initial DOM (Javascript ;))

When you view the source of the page you will notice that there is only 17 `data-at` occurences, while running `document.querySelector("[data-at]")` 29 nodes are returned.

What you are able to get in the JSoup is static content of the page (initial DOM). You wont be able to fetch dynamically created content as you do not run required JS scripts.

In order to overcome this, you will have to either fetch and parse required resources manually (eg trace what AJAX calls are made by the browser) or use headless browser setup. Selenium + headless Chrome should be enough.

Letter option will allow you to scrape ANY posible web application, including SPA apps, which is not possible using plaing Jsoup.

Comment: Thanks Antoniossss, I understand what you are saying and that answered my question. If I may ask one more, when you said I could trace the AJAX calls that were made, I am pretty sure I found the call under the Chrome Dev Tools Network tab which contains all the data I am looking for. Could you provide a suggestion on how to fetch and parse this AJAX response?

Comment: The exact same way you did with initial URL :) Ajax calls are nothing more than plain HTTP requests. So if the browser can do it, so can JSoup (or any other http client utility you would like to use)

Comment: Huh! One catch though... The data that I see when checking out the AJAX call is surrounded in `<script>` tags. To be precise, this is what it looks like:           ```<script>   window.vueAppName = 'dealer_inventory_app';    window.pageData = {{.... all the data that I want is here... }}; </script>``` How can I access this?

Comment: This is plain JS - you have to parse it unfortuneltl. It will be easier for you if you use browser variant I have suggested. On the other hand, since you are on android, I don't know how to do it easily.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know what to do about this, but I'm going to try one more time...  The "Problematic Lines" in your code are these:

> ```
>     doc = Jsoup.connect(queryString.toString()).get();
>     Elements content = doc.select("[data-at]");
> ```

It is the **`queryString`** that you have requested - the **`URL`** points to a page that contains quite a bit of script code.  When you load up a browser and click the button (or menu-option) that reads: **`"View Source"`**, the **`HTML`** you see is not the same exact **`HTML`** that is broadcast to and received by JSoup.

If the **`HTML`** that is broadcast contains any **`<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> ... </SCRIPT>`** in it (and the named **`URL`** in your question does), **AND** those `<SCRIPT>` tags are involved in the initial loading of the page, then JSoup will not know anything about it...  *It only parses what it receives, it cannot process any dynamic content.*

There are four ways that I know of to get the "Post Script Loaded" version of the **`HTML`** from a dynamic web-page, and I will type them here, now.  The first is likely the most popular method (in Java) that I have heard about on Stack Overflow:

- **Selenium**  [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599936/selenium-java-text-retrival-from-h1-tag) will show how the tool can run Java-Script.  These are some [Selenium Docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/).  And then there is [this page](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/) right here has a great "first class" for using the tool to retrieve ***`post-script processed HTML`***.  Again, there is no way JSoup can retrieve HTML that is sent to the browser by script (JS/AJAX/Angular/React) since it ***just a parser***.
- **Puppeteer**  This requires running a language called **Node.js**  Perhaps calling a simple **Node.js** program from Java could work, but it would be a "Two Language" solution.  I've never used it.  Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563410/how-to-get-all-html-data-after-all-scripts-and-page-loading-is-done-puppeteer) that shows getting, sort of, what you are trying to get... The HTML after the script.
- **WebView** Android Java Programmers have a popular class called **`"WebView"`** ([documented here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)), that I have recently been told about (yesterday ... but it has been out for years) that will execute script in a browser, and return the HTML.  Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623503/retrieve-html-element-from-webview-on-click) that shows "JavaScript Injection" to retrieve DOM Tree elements from a "WebView" instance (which is how I was told it was done)
- **Splash** My favorite tool, which I don't think anyone has heard of, but has been the simplest for me... So there is an A.P.I. called the "Splash API".  Here is [their explanation](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for a "Java-Script Rendering Service."  Since this one I have been using... I'll post a code snippet that shows how "Splash Tool" can retrieve ***`post-script processed HTML`*** below.

To run the **`Splash API`** (only if you have access to the **`docker`** loading program) ...  You start a **`Splash Server`** as below.  These two lines are typed into a GCP `(Google Cloud Platform)` Shell instance, and the server starts right up without any configurations:

> Pull the image:
> `$ sudo docker pull scrapinghub/splash`
>
> Start the container:
> `$ sudo docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --rm scrapinghub/splash`
>
> In your code, just prepend the String to your **`URL's`**:
> `"http://localhost:8050/render.html?url="`

So in your code, you would use the following command (instead), and the script would (more likely) load all the HTML Elements that you are not finding:

> ```
> String SPLASH_URL = "http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=";
> doc = Jsoup.connect(SPLASH_URL + queryString.toString()).get();
> ```