# Unable to get page content using jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to get page content for url : "https://cm.netteller.com/login2008/Authentication/Views/Login.aspx?fi=northeast&bn=52075d37adaa8572&burlid=0924e76fe610cedd" using jsoup.

The code snippet is below :

```
String url = "https://cm.netteller.com/login2008/Authentication/Views/Login.aspx?fi=northeast&bn=52075d37adaa8572&burlid=0924e76fe610cedd";
String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
               .userAgent(userAgent)
               .timeout(10*1000)
               .followRedirects(true)
               .get();
String pageTitle = doc.title();
```

But the response in "doc" I am getting is :
[image]

**Please enable javascript to view the page content.**

How can I fix this or use any other way around to get the contents for this url.

I tried "WebClient" with jsoup but got same response.

Thanks

Comment: I think the content is being loaded with Javascript, I believe even the doc.title() is, try selenium instead

Comment: I can't use selenium due to some restrictions. Can you suggest other method @ShivanshPotdar

Comment: Well, go through the js code which is reloading the content and check if there is an iFrame to which you can trace the source to, also I took a look at the js loading code for it and it is loading all the data in realtime so other than using selenium or a Webview on android there are no alternatives.

Comment: My own personal [Canonical Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053142/why-is-my-jsoup-code-not-returning-the-correct-elements/64053949#64053949) about executing the JS on a web-page...  Maybe it will help.  The comment before this one **also** mentioned polling the Web-Server by calling the Java-Script Method that loads your page directly... That also sometimes works, but less likely with a bank web-site that has security checks in it.  It looks like the JS in this particular page is named by some kind of randomly generated **`Token String`**