# How can I scrape the HTML data which I want in Java?

Tags: java, maven, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm practicing and scraping datas from sites. I've stucked within a site which URL is https://www.ilan.gov.tr/ilan/kategori/12/iflas-hukuku-davalari?txv=12&currentPage=1. I want to get Kurum - İlan Numarası - Şehir ( Corporation - Notice Number - City ) datas. I can't scrape div I think. When I compile the code which includes this code `div.search-results-header row` It doesn't work. Also I want to get first 20 pages of this site. How can I do this? There are complicated bunch of code so I'm adding images as attachments. If you tell me at least how can I get Kurum I think I can handle others. Thank you.[image]

However, this is the code what I'm working on for project.

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    File iflasHukuku = new File("/Users/Berkan/Desktop/Iflas Hukuku.txt");
    iflasHukuku.createNewFile();

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(iflasHukuku);
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ilan.gov.tr/ilan/kategori/12/iflas-hukuku-davalari?txv=12&currentPage=1").get();


    for(Element x: document.select(".search-results-table-container container mb-4 ng-tns-c6-3 ng-star-inserted")) {

        final String kurumAdi = x.select("div.search-results-header row").text();
        System.out.println(kurumAdi);

    }

    }
```

Comment: It appears the webpage is Angular App. So, you cannot simply grab the html content using Jsoup.connect because the browser needs to execute the JS to render the page.
So, you have use WebDriver to load the content and get the pageSource and send that to Jsoup.

Comment: Well, the "Turkish Government" website uses `AJAX` / `Java-Script`...  See this - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053142/why-is-my-jsoup-code-not-returning-the-correct-elements/64053949#64053949) - to find ways to execute the Java-Script, because the HTML page that is returned is void any `HTML` whatsoever.  `JSoup` is strictly a parser (and XML-based search) package.  I will try to post my own answer with some solution, soon.

Comment: The `Splash` Tool I usually use couldn't run Angular to completion, so there was just more script in the page I returned.  As the previous comment states, `Selenium` (`WebDriver`) or using the Android `class WebView` will be the only way to see the HTML - _in Java_ - that is on this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the webpage is Angular App. So, you cannot simply grab the HTML content using Jsoup.connect because the browser needs to execute the JS to render the page. So, you have to use WebDriver to load the content and get the pageSource and send that to Jsoup.

See this:

```
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class JSoupTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); //downloads the driver

        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.setHeadless(true);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        driver.get("https://www.ilan.gov.tr/ilan/kategori/12/iflas-hukuku-davalari?txv=12&currentPage=1");

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(webDriver -> driver.getPageSource().contains("İlan Açıklaması"));

        final Document document = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());

        Elements xx = document.select(".search-results-row");

        for (Element x : document.select(".search-results-row")) {

            System.out.println(x.text());
            //parse it further
        }

    }


}
```

**Required Dependencies:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.2-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.13.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you @gtiwari333 . I can't import `io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;` Plus how can I counter the page from 1 to 20 ?

Comment: [Boni Garcia's GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144711/how-can-i-scrape-the-html-data-which-i-want-in-java/64145528#64145528)...  He is a Professor in Italy (according to Google).  Search on Google for more information.  Also, to iterate from 1 .. 20, just wrap the entire method in a `for-loop` that starts at 1, and ends at 20.  Apple Pie.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan its published to Maven just like other jar files. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager Try cleaning your `.m2/repository/io/github/bonigarcia` folder and try again.

Comment: Also, are you using Maven/Gradle at all?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed. But I think I should work on it much more time. I'm not clear on it. I downloaded Chromedriver directly to C:/ root.

Comment: If you use webdrivermamager you don't need to manually download the driver. I've listed it on my dependencies